# HTML Agility Pack get all input fields

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I found some code on the internet that finds all the `href` tags and changes them to google.com, but how can I tell the code to find all the `input` fields and put custom text in there?

This is the code I have right now:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
    att.Value = "http://www.google.com";
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Please, can someone help me, I can't seem to find any information about this on the internet :(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the XPath selector to `//input` to select all the input nodes:

```
foreach (HtmlNode input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
{
    HtmlAttribute att = input.Attributes["value"];
    att.Value = "some text";
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I see now, damn I was so close >.<, Thx!

Comment: It will found those input elements which is in short format? for example <input .... />

Answer (score 2):

Your current code selected all `a` elements (that have a `href` attribute): `"//a[@href]"`.

You want it to select all `input` elements: `"//input"`.

Of course, the inner part of the loop will need to change to match what you are looking for.

I suggest you read up on [XPath](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html).